# cannot print "hello world" on the browser using php language

Tags: php

I'm wondering why I cannot display the simple "hello world" using php language.

This is how my [code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGWfr.jpg) looks like:

```
<?
 echo "Hello world";
?>
```

and this is how the output come out in the browser, nothing display:

[image]

Comment: change `<?` to `<?php` then try

Comment: Use proper tag `<?php ?>`. Also did you run the xammp server for executing this file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure following things for executing php file.

- Php tag should be properly open and close `<?php ... ?>`
- You xampp server is properly running.
- You are accessing file by putting correct path.

Comment: i got it. Thank you so much.. I did not notice that at all. Silly mistake. I follow the tutorial in youtube but didn't notice that php